# How to connect to online MongoDB database from Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I want to connect to an online MongoDB database hosted at Mlab, from inside a Spring Boot application.

I have configured the application.properties with the URI:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri = mongodb://myuser:mypassword@ds129532.mlab.com:29532/consilium-dev
```

However, the application still connects to the local MongoDB database. How can I make it connect to the Mlab database?

**SOLUTION:**
The resources folder was not situated in the right folder. It should be in src/java/resources

Comment: which version of spring data and mongodb java driver are you using?

Comment: @harshavmb, I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.4, and the MongoDB version from mLab is 3.2.14

Comment: Can you try this `# mongo connections
spring.data.mongodb.host=ds129532.mlab.com
spring.data.mongodb.port=29532
spring.data.mongodb.username=myuser
spring.data.mongodb.password=mypassword
spring.data.mongodb.database=consilium-dev` in your application.properties?

Comment: You can try this as well `spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://myuser:mypassword@ds129532.mlab.com:29532

spring.data.mongodb.database=consilium-dev`

Comment: that is just a different way of writing the same thing. Your app is probably not picking up the config file correctly. Are you sure it is in the right location? You can test it easily by adding a `@Value("${something}") String something;` and adding the something tag to the properties file then printing it out.

Comment: @p.streef, I think the application.poperties is not in the right directory. Now it's in src/main/resources. Is this correct?

Comment: That is correct for a default spring boot app. I will delete that answer that should have been a comment when I'm able because the app won't let me...

Comment: @p.streef, you were right. That was the problem. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

In my case, spring boot was connecting to the uri specified in `application.properties` file while testing in my PC but once deployed to heroku, it always connected to the `localhost` irrespective of what was specified in `application.properties`. Solution was to pass the database uri as command line arguments while deploying the jar to the server because this will take precedence over the properties. To do so, create a Procfile like:

```
web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT -Dspring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://<user>:<pass>@<host>:<port>/<db> -jar my-app.jar
```

And using heroku toolkit, run following command.

```
heroku deploy:jar -j my-app.jar -i Procfile --app <host-name>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using database values in the `application.properties` didn't work for me for online mongodb.
 It works fine for local db. But Once I google and found an example online where they added it in this way below and it worked for me.

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@ds261828.mlab.com:61828/springdb.
```